# On the convergence/divergence of multiple improper integrals

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

If a function has multiple intervals over its domain where an improper integral may be taken, is it guaranteed that they will all be convergent/divergent?

Ex: the function $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+2x}$ has vertical asymptotes at $x=-2$ and $x=0$. Trying to integrate using $-2$ or $0$ as the upper bound always results in divergence, as does integrating over $[1, ∞)$.

Does this mean that, if one of a function’s asymptotes yields a divergent integral, it can be assumed that the others will also diverge?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear to me. But take

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x\sqrt{4-x}}.$$

This function has two asymptotes, one at $0$ and another at $4.$ Depending on the domain of integration, it will converge or diverge. For example,  it will diverge on $[0,10]$ but converge on $[1,10].$ So the two asymptotes are kind of different.

However, if you fix your domain of integration and there is one point within your domain where the integral diverges, the integral will diverge on your entire domain.